# Using python modules from ROS2 packages

Tags: ros, tf2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS2 dashing and I want to work with the geometry2/tf2_ros package which is available at https://index.ros.org/p/tf2_ros/#dashing.

I am sure this is a very basic question, but I am having a hard time finding documentation on how to do stuff in ROS2.

- How do I install the package so I can import the modules to my python scripts?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I think I have to rephrase the question. I allready have the tf2 package installed and I can run the static_transform_publisher from terminal, but I am having trouble importing the tf2_ros module to python when I am writing my own nodes - keep getting "no module named tf2_ros".

So what I am asking is how do I make the package available so that I can import the python modules when writing my own python nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350932/using-python-modules-from-ros2-packages/) by [svintissen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53859/svintissen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2020-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you're having a hard time finding documentation about this as installing a package hasn't changed between ROS 1 and ROS 2. If a package is released, and you're using ROS on any supported Debian or Ubuntu flavour, installing it would be a matter of:

```
sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-package-name
```

so in this case:

```
sudo apt install ros-dashing-tf2-ros
```

Note that this is how you would install *any* Debian/Ubuntu package, not just released ROS packages. Which is probably another reason why it's not overly documented.

I'm not saying it's a stupid or unnecessary question btw, just proferring possible rationales for why you cannot find any documentation about this subject.

---

Edit:

> I am having trouble importing the tf2_ros module to python when I am writing my own nodes - keep getting "no module named tf2_ros". [..] So what I am asking is how do I make the package available so that I can import the python modules when writing my own python nodes?

If that is your actual question then it appears it's actually a duplicate of #q309889.

Summary: the Python side to `tf2_ros` was only released into Eloquent, not Dashing.

---

Edit 2: it seems you asked a similar question in #q350839. @tfoote remarks there the *package* `tf2_ros` was released into all ROS 2 versions, which is technically correct. I do believe that the *Python side* of `tf2_ros` was only included in the Eloquent version though (because of [this comment](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/99#issuecomment-540751125) by Chris):

> This was merged into master, and will be part of the Eloquent release: https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Eloquent-Elusor/
>
> The changes were too invasive to backport into Dashing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [svintissen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53859/svintissen/) on 2020-04-29**:
Thanks, I think I have to rephrase the question. I allready have the tf2 package installed and I can run the static_transform_publisher from terminal, but I am having trouble importing the tf2_ros module to python when I am writing my own nodes - keep getting "no module named tf2_ros".

So what I am asking is how do I make the package available so that I can import the python modules when writing my own python nodes?